# How do I retrieve a user's LogIn name through the Created By colum using javascript

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, sharepoint-online

I have a requirement to retrieve the user email from created by column.  I have tried with `get_lookupValue()`, but I got system object error message.  Is there  any solution to retrieve the user email from created by column using JavaScript?

Code attempted:

```
var Item=get_item('Author'); 
var user=Item.get_lookupValue();
```

Comment: Add code you are using, to help you better

Comment: var Item=get_item('Author');
var user=Item.get_lookupValue();

Answer (score 0):

`get_item('Author');` should return a user object.  Simply use the `get_email()` method to get the user email:

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('My list');
var item = list.getItemById(1);
ctx.load(item);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function(){
    alert(item.get_item('Author').get_email());
}, /* error handling here */ );
```